# random choice em python

Tags: python, random

Sou iniciante e estou criando uma um programa para fazer tabuadas, mas não queria que o programa seguisse uma ordem crescente como: "1x1, 1x2" e assim por diante. Então usei uma função "random.choice" para poder mostrar as tabuadas de modo aleatório, criei um lista para mostrar as tabuadas na tela, mas não sei como adicionar e verificar a resposta.

```
import random

tabuada = int(input('Digite o número da tabuada: \n'))
if tabuada == 1:
   print(random.choice(['1x1 = ','1x2 = ','1x3 = ','1x4 = ','1x5 = ','1x6 = ','1x7 = ','1x8 = ','1x9 = ','1x10 = ']))
```

Comment: A dúvida ainda está confusa e ambígua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ler o valor da tabuada, manteremos o código da pergunta:

```
numero = int(input('Digite o número da tabuada: \n'))
```

Se desejamos a tabuada de 1 a 10, sorteamos um fator neste intervalo:

```
fator = choice(range(1, 11))
```

Assim, será solicitado ao usuário o resultado de `numero` vezes `fator`:

```
resposta = int(input(f'Quanto é {numero}x{fator}? '))
```

E, para exibir o resultado do programa:

```
 print('Acertou' if resposta == numero * fator else 'Errooou!')
```

Ficando o código completo:

```
from random import choice

numero = int(input('Digite o número da tabuada: '))
fator = choice(range(1, 11))

resposta = int(input(f'Quanto é {numero}x{fator}? '))

print('Acertou' if resposta == numero * fator else 'Errooou!')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FriendlyVillainousCertification) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/6c727cb5d05541a5c2c1a94c7d31ade9)</sup>

Se a intenção será solicitar todos os fatores de 1 a 10, basta utilizar a função `shuffle` ao invés da `choice` para desordenar os fatores de forma aleatória, solicitando ao usuário a resposta dentro de um laço de repetição.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja `implementar` um programa que que gere cada uma das `tabuadas` de forma aleatória.

Para desenvolver este algoritmo, você irá precisar realizar o sorteio com o método `choice` da classe `random`.

Além disso você tem que tomar cuidado para que os números sorteados `não se repitam`.

Diante destas observações desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Cabeçalho do programa
print(f'=' * 36)
print(f'\033[34m{f"Gerador de tabuadas aleatórias":^36}\033[m')
print('=' * 36)

# Importações de bibliotecas
from random import choice

# Capturando e tratando o número digitado:
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Gerando tabuada aleatória de: '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')      
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')

# Lista de valores a ser sorteados:
valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Sorteio e exibição dos valores:
print(f'\033[32mTabuada aleatória de {n}')
for c in range(1, 11):
    x = choice(valores)
    prod = (n * x)
    print(f'{n} x {x} = {prod}')
    # Exclusão do valor sorteado para não incorrer em sorteios duplicados:
    valores.remove(x)
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/cwpbvsrv-solkarped).

Observe que este programa foi desenvolvido da seguinte forma:

O primeiro `bloco` de códigos forma o cabeçalho do programa.

O segundo bloco de códigos organiza as bibliotecas utilizadas. O próximo bloco realiza a captura e tratamento do valor digitado. O próximo bloco armazena a lista da qual realizará o sorteio dos valores.

O principal bloco de códigos é justamente o último. É neste código, onde ocorre de fato o `sorteio`, o `produto` dos valores e a `exibição` dos resultados. Em seguida, ocorre a `remoção` do valor sorteado da lista `valores`, evitando desta forma, que o valor sorteado `anteriormente` seja novamente sorteado.

A partir disso o programa exibirá a `tabuada` de um determinado número `n` de forma não sequencial e sim, de forma `aleatória`.